# Extract data from an Object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a SQL query that returns a list of deals which have this structure : deal_id, value_1, value_2, ..., value 50

I put the result of this query in a list like this (using org.hibernate.SQLQuery) :

```
SQLQuery select = session.createSQLQuery(QUERY);
List result = select.list();
```

Then I use this loop to iterate through the results :

```
for (Object o : result) {

}
```

When debugging, o looks like this (one String, 50 BigDecimal) :

```
[SSA12325, 0, 1.012, 1.1235, ..., 0]
```

I want to extract the deal_id, how do I do that ?

I tried to convert o to a List, but I got a classCastException : [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Comment: why u want to convert object O to list ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here your `Object o` is `Array of Object` because it contains all Objects such as String and Integer.
So, try:

```
Object[] objArray = (Object[]) o;
```

then do whatever you want to do with your array.

Comment: O is the element of list.How can be the array of object ?

Comment: @Niks Tyagi: Imagine, this is valid code: `Object o = new Object[5];`. An object can hold everything! So, even a `Object o = new ArrayList<Object[]>();` will work properly.

Comment: hehehehe i m not fresher in java that you are providing me the basic.I  was having some misunderstanding regarding the qustion